conditional rendering a table in next js
I have a table of values with varying values of location. I am trying to filter the rows in the database by matching the location value. The code is
'use client';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const styles = {
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  header: {
    width: '100%',
    padding: '1rem',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottom: '1px solid #eaeaea',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  },
  createButton: {
    padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
    backgroundColor: '#0070f3',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: '1rem',
  },
  headerText: {
    flex: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: '1.25rem',
    color: '#333',
  },
  logOutButton: {
    padding: '0.4rem 1rem',
    backgroundColor: '#FF999C',
    color: 'white',
    border: '0.5px',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: '1rem',
  },
  contentWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: '1rem',
    overflowY: 'auto',
  },
  main: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
  },
  table: {
    width: '100%',
    borderCollapse: 'collapse',
    borderRadius: '10px',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    border: '1px solid #000',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
  },
  th: {
    border: '1px solid #000',
    padding: '8px',
    paddingLeft: '10px',
    backgroundColor: '#334',
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  td: {
    border: '1px solid #000',
    padding: '8px',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FAF9F6',
    color: '#000',
  },
  footer: {
    padding: '0.5rem',
    borderTop: '2px solid #eaeaea',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'black',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  },
  modalOverlay: {
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 1000,
  },
  modalContent: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: '2rem',
    borderRadius: '10px',
    width: '90%',
    maxWidth: '600px',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
  },
  input: {
    width: '100%',
    padding: '0.5rem',
    marginBottom: '0.5rem',
    color: 'black',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    border: '1px solid #ccc',
    fontSize: '1rem',
  },
  modalButtons: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  addButton: {
    padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
    backgroundColor: '#0070f3',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: '1rem',
  },
  cancelButton: {
    padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
    backgroundColor: '#E97451',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: '1rem',
  },
  deleteButton: {
    padding: '0.1rem 1rem',
    backgroundColor: '#E97451',
    color: 'white',
    border: 'none',
    borderRadius: '5px',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: '0.8rem',
  },
  '@media (max-width: 1024px)': {
    container: {
      padding: '0.5rem',
    },
    headerText: {
      fontSize: '1rem',
    },
    createButton: {
      padding: '0.3rem 0.6rem',
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
    },
    table: {
      width: '100%',
    },
    modalContent: {
      width: '80%',
    },
  },
  '@media (max-width: 768px)': {
    container: {
      padding: '0.5rem',
    },
    headerText: {
      fontSize: '1rem',
    },
    createButton: {
      padding: '0.3rem 0.6rem',
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
    },
    table: {
      width: '100%',
    },
    modalContent: {
      width: '90%',
    },
  },
  '@media (max-width: 480px)': {
    container: {
      padding: '0.25rem',
    },
    header: {
      flexDirection: 'column',
      alignItems: 'flex-start',
    },
    createButton: {
      padding: '0.3rem 0.5rem',
      fontSize: '0.75rem',
    },
    headerText: {
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
    },
    table: {
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
    },
    modalContent: {
      width: '95%',
    },
  },
};


const Dashboard = () => {
  const [streetLights, setStreetLights] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({ location: '' });
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState('');
  const [newLight, setNewLight] = useState({
    id: '',
    dateOfFixing: '',
    intensity: '',
    workingCondition: '',
    location: '',
  });
  const [editingLight, setEditingLight] = useState(null);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);

  // Fetch street lights when the filter changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStreetLights = async () => {
      const query = new URLSearchParams(filter).toString();  // Convert filter to query string
      const res = await fetch(`/api/streetlights?${query}`); // Append query string to the API endpoint
      const data = await res.json();
      setStreetLights(data); // Update state with filtered data
    };
  
    fetchStreetLights();
  }, [filter]); // Re-run the effect when the filter changes
  

  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const fetchStreetLights = async () => {
        const query = new URLSearchParams(filter).toString();
        const res = await fetch(`/api/streetlights?${query}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        setStreetLights(data);
      };

      fetchStreetLights();
    }, 100);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [filter]);

  // Socket connection for real-time updates
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3001');

    socket.on('streetLightsData', (data) => {
      setStreetLights(data);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
    setFilter({ ...filter, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });  // Update the filter state
  };
  

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/streetlights/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      setStreetLights((prev) => prev.filter((light) => light.id !== id));
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to delete street light');
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setNewLight((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await fetch('/api/streetlights', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(newLight),
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      const newLight = await res.json();
      setStreetLights((prev) => [...prev, newLight]);
      setNewLight({
        id: '',
        dateOfFixing: '',
        intensity: '',
        workingCondition: true,
        location: '',
      });
    }
  };

  const startEditing = (light) => {
    setEditingLight(light);
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleEditChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setEditingLight((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    window.location.href = '/api/auth/logout';
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <header style={styles.header}>
        <button style={styles.createButton} onClick={handleOpenModal}>
          Create Light
        </button>
        <div style={styles.headerText}>Street Lights Dashboard</div>
        <button style={styles.logOutButton} onClick={handleLogout}>
          Log out
        </button>
      </header>
      <header style={styles.header}>
        <div>
          <select
            name="location"
            value={filter.location}
            onChange={handleFilterChange}
            style={styles.input}
          >
            <option value="">All Locations</option>
            <option value="Sriperumbudur">Sriperumbudur</option>
            <option value="Location2">Location 2</option>
            <option value="Location3">Location 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style={styles.headerText}>Street Lights Dashboard</div>
      </header>

      <div style={styles.contentWrapper}>
        <main style={styles.main}>
          <table style={styles.table}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style={styles.th}>ID</th>
                <th style={styles.th}>Date of Fixing</th>
                <th style={styles.th}>Intensity</th>
                <th style={styles.th}>Status</th>
                <th style={styles.th}>Location</th>
                <th style={styles.th}>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {streetLights.length > 0 ? (
              streetLights.map((light) => (
                <tr key={light.id}>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{light.id}</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{light.dateOfFixing}</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{light.intensity}</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{light.workingCondition}</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>{light.location}</td>
                  <td style={styles.td}>
                    <button style={styles.deleteButton} onClick={() => handleDelete(light.id)}>
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))
            ) : (
              <tr>
                <td style={styles.td} colSpan="6">No street lights found for this location.</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
          </table>
        </main>
      </div>
      <footer style={styles.footer}>
        <p>Street Light Management System</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

It still doesn't filter the values by location. How do I do that?
Tried to print the lights with the location selected from the drop down menu but end up getting all the lights

Using the callback form of setState (in this case, setFilter) is recommended when your new state depends on the previous state. This ensures that you always get the most up-to-date value of the state, even if multiple state updates happen in quick succession.
const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
  setFilter(filter => ({
    ...filter,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }));
};

If there are multiple updates to the filter state in quick succession (e.g., multiple input changes), using the callback ensures that each update works with the most recent version of the state.

It looks like the error is in the handleFilterChange function.
If I'm not wrong when an option is selected, let's say "Location 2", you're expecting something like this:
{ location: 'Location2' }

but this is what's really happens:
{ location: '', 'Location 2': 'Location2' }

Try with this:
const handleFilterChange = (e) => {
    setFilter({ location: e.target.value });
};

